# Why I get "Keyset does not exist" exception everytime I try to digital sign a pdf document using dbAutoTrack PDFWriter?

Tags: .net, certificate, x509certificate2

I have implemented a web app using .NET Framework 4.6 and Visual Basic. My app generates digital signed pdf files using the lib PDFWriter of DBAutoTrack.

The certificate (e-seal) which is used to sign the pdf is stored as varbinary(max) in a database on MS SQL Server. It is purchased from a CA and the private key is generated using RSA and key sizes of 2048 and 4096 bits.

In order to digital sign the pdf I load the certificate from the database as an array of bytes, using the following code:

```
Dim signature As New dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.PDFDigitalSignature

signature.X509Certificate = New X509Certificate2(<certificate as byte[]>, <my password>, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)

signature.Date = DateTime.Now
signature.DetachSignature = False
signature.MaxSignatureSize = 6000
signature.RootTrusted = True
signature.Visible = False

Dim MergedDocument As New Document
...
MergedDocument.DigitalSignature = signature
```

Now, when I call the MergedDocument.Generate() method to generate the pdf, I get the "Keyset does not exist" exception.

However, when I load the certificate from the windows certificate store, as shown below, I do not get the exception.

```
Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine)           store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)

Dim certCollection As X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates
Dim currentCerts As X509Certificate2Collection = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, False)

Dim signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, <certificate's thumbprint>, False)

Return signingCert(0)
```

Does anyone have an idea why I get the exception when I try to sign the PDF having the certificate loaded from the db?

I have given full control permissions to the application pool of the web app to the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys but didn't fixed the issue.